# Howto grep 2 words to be highlighted

Tags: bash, grep

I've seen few similar questions, but none answers this problem.
I'd like to search a maillog for **status** of emails to particular **user/domain**.  So I need to grep for email (ie **@gmail.com**)  and status (ie '**=sent**').  I know I can just do one after another, but I would like to have both words **highlighted**!  So if I can do it: 
`grep 'gmail.com' /var/log/maillog -A 2 -B 2|grep '=sent'`

 only "**=sent**" will be highlighted.  If I do it: 
`grep 'gmail.com.*=sent' /var/log/maillog -A 2 -B 2` 
Then everything in between will also be highlighted.
Using `-P` option it wouldn't highlight matched pattern. `awk` I also wasn't able to get this result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` implementations that color their output usually have a default setting of `--color=auto` that inserts color codes only when printing to a terminal. When printing to a file or pipe, color is automatically disabled, but can be enabled manually.

Since your search strings `gmail.com` and `=sent` can never overlap*, you can just enable `--color=always` and run the colored output through `grep` again. Here I also

```
grep -C2 --color=always -F 'gmail.com' /var/log/maillog |
grep -aC2 '=sent'
```

* In general, this trick does not work. Assume you where searching `ab` and `bc` in the line `abc`, then the first command would print `…ab…c` where `…` are invisible escape sequences that tell your terminal how to color the text. Because of those escape sequences, the second command would print nothing, because `bc` is not in the output; only `b…c` is, but that is something different.

<sub>Note: I mostly copied your approach with -A2 -B2 which contains a few flaws. Possible fixes depend on your precise requirements.</sub>

Comment: Thanks @Socowi, this seems shorter one liner, and it works.  Useful to use `--color=always`  I assume there is no such thing as to have it in one pattern in AND manner as it is `grep 'gmail\.com\|=sent'` in the OR manner.

Comment: @DenisZ It is possible to have a single pattern that searches `x` *and* `y`, namely `x.*y|y.*x`. When you can use PCREs (e.g. `-P`) it could be even possible to have an uncolored middle part `.*`. But the command/regex would be way more complicated, slower, and may require experimental features (e.g. combining `-z` and `-P`). The details depend on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with this?

```bash
grep 'gmail\.com.*=sent' /var/log/maillog -A 2 -B 2 |
grep -F -e 'gmail.com' -e '=sent' -A 2 -B 2
```

Comment: No, I've tried this but it maches OR not both  words.  -A 2 -B 2 is to show 2 preceding and 2 trailing lines after the match

Comment: @DenisZ OK, I fixed my answer, but because of `-A 2 -B 2` some `gmail.com` and `=sent` might get highlighted in the prepended and appended lines

Comment: I don't get any match when using -F, but it actually works without it so I used `grep 'gmail\.com.*=sent' /var/log/maillog -A 2 -B2 |grep 'gmail.com\|=sent' -A 2 -B 2`.  Not sure what '-F' option do, as I didn't find it in man

Comment: @DenisZ `-F` is for treating the pattern as a literal string instead of a regex (I was wrong to use it in the first `grep`)

Comment: Thanks I found `-F`in the manual , and it also works I didn't use `-e` in my statement

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` and the red color:

```
awk '/gmail\.com/ && /=sent/ {gsub(/gmail\.com|=sent/,"\033[01;31m&\033[0m"); print}'
```

With `sed` (and `bash`):

```
sed -E $'/gmail\.com/{/=sent/s/(gmail\.com|=sent)/\033[01;31m&\033[0m/g}'
```

Comment: Thanks @Renaud, `awk` didn't print out those extra 2 lines, but `sed` did so it is a solution that I can use, but I used grep and pipe it to awk/sed.  I presumed you meant it this way.